# I have basic functionality Accelerometer code, now I need to make it display text or play audio, etc

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, accelerometer

I was creating a project for a learning exercise, using the accelerometer.

I have the basic functionality of the code, now I just need to make it do something. Display a message, play audio, or display an image.

**!! EDIT !!**

```
//  ACViewController.m
//  Accelerometer
//


#import "ACViewController.h"

@interface ACViewController ()

- (void) startAccelerometer;
- (void) stopAccelerometer;

@end

@implementation ACViewController

- (void) accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration

{     //!!EDIT!!
    double const kThreshold = 2.0;
if ( fabsf(acceleration.x) > kThreshold
    || fabsf(acceleration.y) > kThreshold
    || fabsf(acceleration.z) > kThreshold)

    UILabel * theLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 640)];
    theLabel.text = @"Hello earth";
    [self.theLabel addSubView:theLabel];
```

//END OF EDIT
    }

```
- (void)startAccelerometer {
    UIAccelerometer *accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accelerometer.delegate = self;
    accelerometer.updateInterval = 0.25;
}

- (void)stopAccelerometer {
    UIAccelerometer *accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accelerometer.delegate = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self startAccelerometer];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self stopAccelerometer];
}
```

@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@

Header File:

```
//
//  ACViewController.h
//  Accelerometer


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ACViewController : UIViewController <UIAccelerometerDelegate>

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example for adding an image (and assuming you use ARC):

In the line with the NSLog, type:

```
[self.view addSubView:[[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"]]];
```

Example for a label (ARC):

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 640)];
label.text = @"Hello earth";
[self.view addSubView:label];
```

When not using ARC, release the instances after adding them to the view.

Comment: I edited part of the code that I added for the label (SEE ABOVE). I am getting two errors, on the first line of the label code you provided it says "expected expression", on the third line it says "No visible @interface for 'UILabel' declares the selector 'addSubView'

Comment: [self.theLabel addSubView:theLabel]; is wrong, your viewcontroller has no property "theLabel", but it has a property "view", so my code should be correct...

Comment: I wasn't suggesting your code was bad. I know I'm messing up, just not sure how to fix it. I am very new to xCode and any kind of programming. It's a very frustrating learning curve. I'll have to put the accelerometer stuff aside for another day. Thanks a lot for your time though.

Comment: Hey, no worries! I just tested the code on an actual device and the reason is simple: in your ViewController interface, you must declare that it conforms to the UIViewControllerDelegate protocol with this: <UIViewControllerDelegate>. I uploaded a sample project here: http://weibezahn.com/dlstuff/AccelTest.zip